# PowerShell App Deployment MSU

Tags: powershell

Using the powershell app deployment toolkit I am trying to write a script to push a Windows update (MSU).

This is what I have, but it does not seem to work?

Execute-Process -Path 'Windows6.1-KB3033929-x64.msu' -Parameters "/quiet"

Comment: "but it does not seem to work?" - How? What? Errors? Nothing? Any info?

Comment: Path should be `wusa.exe`. The msu-path is an argument

Comment: What is `Execute-Process`?

Comment: It's from the App Deployment Toolkit. Must be something new. There have been a slew of questions regarding functions from it lately.

Answer (score 1):

Msu-files are installed using `wusa.exe`. Try:

```
$PathToMsu="$PSScriprRoot\somefile.msu" Execute-Process -Path 'wusa.exe' -Parameters "`"$PathToMsu`" /quiet /norestart"
```

You might also consider using `Install-MSUpdates` from the toolkit which does this for you for every file in a directory.